# Angular router-outlet child can't fill space

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular-flex-layout

I have a problem with filling all available space with the router-outlet.

I use angular/flex-layout for my application. And the component loaded with the router doesn't take all available place.

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlexFill>
  <maat-top-bar></maat-top-bar>
  <router-outlet fxFlex></router-outlet>
</div>
```

[Screenshot of app & dom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0iYD.png)

The router-outlet take space instead of child component. On screenshot the component is `<maat-home></maat-home>`. In the DOM tree this component is placed after the router-outlet.

What can I do so the component `<maat-home></maat-home>` will take the remaining space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way. 
The router-outlet is hidden and the component added on DOM have the attribute `fxFlexFill` for filling all available space.

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlexFill>
  <maat-top-bar class="top-bar"></maat-top-bar>
  <div fxFlex>
   <router-outlet class="hidden-router"></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

The class `hidden-router`

```
.hidden-router {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And the component

```
<div fxFlexFill="">
  I filling all remaining space
</div>
```

Comment: I believe you can just use "fxFill" instead of fxFlexFill="" or at least that's working in my case

Answer (score 5):

Adding `fxFlex` to the `<router-outlet>` is probably not what you want.
The component added by the router is added as a sibling, not as a child of `<router-outlet>`

Comment: Then what should we do???????

Answer (score 1):

You can put this style in the child component :

```
:host {
  width: 100%;
}
```

or this in the composant style of the router-outlet:

```
:host ::ng-deep router-outlet + * {
    width: 100%;
}
```